# Open given url in OpenERP in new tab

Tags: odoo

How to open **url** link on new tab instead of pop up in OpenERP on button click?

Comment: button click you cannot do anything. If its a link then  u can right click it and  then choose open  in  new tab  .  however this will  only work in version 7. Version 6 does not open the tab as per  the link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In V7, ctrl-clicking on most links works as expected (i.e. open link in a new tab).

In 6.1 you have to create a new tab by Ctrl-clicking on the OpenERP logo (in the top left corner), which opens a new tab with the default screen and then navigate from there to the page you need (tedious, I know...). You can also try this addon: https://code.launchpad.net/~h-jaroslav/+junk/web_tabs which opens links in tabs inside the web client tab.

Answer (score 0):

First you have mark the following options from your browser preferences

- "Open New window in a new Tab" and
- "When I Open a link in a New Tab,switch it to immediately"

Second, you just set your mouse over to link in openerp and press Scroll key.
The page will Open/display in New Tab